# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' on the bean tag recursively

Tags: spring

I am getting below error:

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

my context.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans default-autowire="no"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

      <bean id="fileParser" class="com.xxx.xx.xx.oxm.FileInputParser" >
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref ="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "jaxb2Marshaller" class = "org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name = "classesToBeBound">
            <array>
                <value>com.xxx.xx.xx.oxm.XutoxenPathInfo</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `schemaLocation` is not written correctly. The location needs to follow the namespace name.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

Yours wasn't doing that. It was

```
beansNS 
contextNS 
contextLocation
beansLocation
```

Comment: sorry i could not get you, xsi:schemalocation is same as you mentioned

Comment: @mahesh No it is not. The declarations are not in the correct order.

Comment: That is working now.you are genious. I need to add few more. I am updating the post. could you please help me with the error.

Comment: getting error:The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config' when added below        <context:annotation-config />
  
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.xx"></context:component-scan>

Comment: @mahesh I recommend you ask a new question and provide all the relevant details. Also, do a search for that first. There are similar questions out there.